# HTML not linking to CSS file django

Tags: html, css, django

I know there are so many questions on this but I'm yet to find a solution. I have the below folder structure for my django app:

[image]

I then reference the styles.css file from my index.html page, like so:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
{% load static%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
```

but no matter what I change in my css file it doesn't affect my webpage.

css file if useful:

```
.form-details {
text-align: center;
color: Tomato;
background-color: red;}
```

Comment: add you settings.py

Comment: Sorry what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `{% load static %}` line to the top of your `index.html` file.

And also be sure that you correctly set static files direction in the `settings.py` file.

For example,

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_assets'),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```